# Too many arguments to method call ,expected 1 have 2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm calling a `JSON` URL from the `NSURL` class. My URL is:

```
like://Design_Time_Addresses/IServices/RoleService/json/Role/?name=%@",[textField text]];
```

When I write "doctor" in the textfield I have to get all the details of doctor through that URL. Similarly when I write "engineer" I have to get all the details of engineer. So it means what I type in the textfield, the name in URL  should be replaced with the textfield value. But when I write the code like this:

```
NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Design_Time_Addresses/ICloudServices/RoleService/json/Role/?name=%@",[textField text]];
NSString *jsonStr =[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[jsonStr JSONValue]];
```

As shown here I am using the `NSURL` class to get this URL.

I am getting an error in the `NSURL` class. How do I pass the text fields value to a URL?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? and on what line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First line should be

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Design_Time_Addresses/ICloudServices/RoleService/json/Role/?name=%@",[textField text]];
NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

`NSURL URLWithString` expects a single string argument, while you are providing two. Since you probably want to construct a single string from the `@"http://..."` string and `[textField text]`, you should use an `NSString` method to concatenate them. You can't rely on `NSURL` to concatenate the string for you.

Comment: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ICloudServices/RoleService/json/Role/?name=%@",[textField text]];
    NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; 
       
 NString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
    
   NSMutableDictionary *jsonDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[jsonStr JSONValue]];
   result.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonDetails];Can I know where Im i going wrong?

Comment: I would suggest verifying after each line of code that it did what you expect it to do.